# Error code 0xc0000135 in Qt Creator with OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Im a novice coder, that needs to make a simple UI - i've chosen to do it in Qt Creator.

As i need to incorporate a webcam feed, i've been advised to use OpenCV.
I've followed the following guide: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows

However im running into the problem "Error code 0xc0000135" when i try to debug my code.

I've added the different PATHs to the Enviromental Variables as requested in the guide. Anyone with a kind idea of where the issue might lie, or can it be anywhere in the process?

Cheers!

Comment: It is Qt, not QT. QT is for Quick Time.

Comment: Sorry, corrected it.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to S.O.! It would help if you could provide more information about your question. Where does the error code show? is it a Run time log or build time? What does the code look like? Have you tried running your program under a debugger (the green play button with a bug on it in QtCreator)?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest that unless you are going to do a lot of computer vision stuff, that you leave OpenCV for the native Qt approach which is `QMediaPlayer`.

In QtCreator the example is built in, just select "Welcome" -> "Examples" -> "search for video player" -> "select example.

[image]

Or if you prefer browsing online, [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html) it is.

If you still want to use OpenCV, please add more details to the question so it is easier to help you!